# compare pandas Timestamp to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time column in a pandas data frame that looks like this

```
df.time[df.last_valid_index()]

Timestamp('2022-03-31 08:26:00')
```

I would like to do a simple operation like

```
start = time(9, 26, 00).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

start <= df.time[df.last_valid_index()]
```

but I get the following errors

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'
```

how do I make the pandas Timestamp compatible with time object such that I can compare them?

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question and expected ouput?

Answer (score 1):

You need compare datetimes, not strings generate `strftime` method:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('09:26:00')
print (start)
2022-03-31 09:26:00
```

Comment: thanks. That does it. How would I reverse the operation and convert the Timestamp('2022-03-31 08:26:00') in the df such that it was comparable with start = time(9, 26, 00).strftime("%H:%M:%S")?

Comment: You mean comparing two string dates?

Comment: @DaveTheRave - do you need compare strings `HH:MM:SS` ? then use `df.time[df.last_valid_index()].strftime("%H:%M:%S")`